# Password of private key for installation of SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, bitbucket

I opened certificate for SSL - Bitbucket. while opening import wizard it needs password.
Where do i get that passsword?

Comment: Please, provide more information. It helps to solve your issue

Comment: New Project...Have to Install SSL Certificate for bitbucket. I dont know how to install? I dont know how to fetch password for private key while opening Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

TLS certificates don't have passwords, but the keys they're associated with do. That's set up when the key is created, so you'll need to talk to whomever created the key.

Comment: Mine Certificate is.P12...from where do i get Private key password while opening Certificate?

Comment: From the person who created it.

Comment: server.port=80
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.require-ssl=true
server.secure=true
server.ssl.key-store=D:/Atlassian/ApplicationData/Bitbucket/shared/config/ssl-keystore/<cert name>
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12
server.ssl.key-password=given
server.ssl.client-auth=need                                      Is there any error in above Bitbucket.properties??

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. You need to ask the person who gave you this stuff, not me.

Comment: Thanks Jim....Just to confirm...Public and Private key password will be given only by owner of the certificate?

Comment: If a key has a password, then the person who set that password will either have to provide it, or give you a copy that doesn't have a password. Otherwise you cannot use that key.